# How to remove values from a map in Terraform that match a key value

Tags: terraform

I have a sample map like below and am trying to remove any accounts that have a key2 value matching 'bong'.

So the starting map would look like this:

```
sample_map={
  account1 = {
      key1       ="foo"
      key2       ="bar"
  }
  account2 = {
      key1       ="bing"
      key2       ="bong"
  }
}
```

And the end result should look like this:

```
new_map={
  account1 = {
      key1       ="foo"
      key2       ="bar"
  }
}
```

I've tried manipulating the following for loop but it only works if var.exclude matches the label (not a key).

```
new_map = { for k, v in var.sample_map : k => v if ! contains(var.exclude, k) }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were almost there, if I understand correctly. It should be:

```
contains(values(v), var.exclude)
```

The working example is below:

```
variable "sample_map" {

  default ={
    account1 = {
        key1       ="foo"
        key2       ="bar"
    }
    account2 = {
        key1       ="bing"
        key2       ="bong"
    }  
  }
}

variable "exclude" {
  default = "bong"
}


output "test" {
  value = { for k, v in var.sample_map: k => v if ! contains(values(v), var.exclude) }
}
```

Which gives:

```
test = {
  "account1" = {
    "key1" = "foo"
    "key2" = "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nailed it, thx! It's difficult to find good examples of If Expressions. Appreciate the help!

Comment: This answer would also remove objects that have a value for `key1` matching `var.exclude` (objects for which `key1` matches `bong` would also be removed). If you know that all objects will contain a `key2`, you can define the guard as `if v.key2 != "bong"`. If you do not, e.g. `if lookup(v, "key2", null) != var.exclude`.