# terraform aws_ram_principal_association exlcude master account id

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to exclude a string which contains the "523134851043" account which holds some shared resources from the **aws_ram_principal_association**?

*settings.yaml*

```
aws:
  - accounts: ciss-goesaws-test
    id: "523134851043"
    private_subnets:
      -
        nat_gw: true
        az: eu-central-1a
        short: a
        cidr: 10.44.4.96/27
      -
        nat_gw: false
        az: eu-central-1b
        short: b
        cidr: 10.44.5.128/27
      -
        nat_gw: false
        az: eu-central-1c
        short: c
        cidr: 10.44.6.160/27
```

*variables.tf*

```
variable "aws" {
  type = list(object({
    accounts: string
    id: string
    public_subnets: list(object({
      nat_gw: bool
      az: string
      short: string
      cidr: string
    }))
    private_subnets: list(object({
      nat_gw: bool
      az: string
      short: string
      cidr: string
    }))
  }))
}
```

```
locals {
  public_ram = flatten([
    for a in var.aws : [
      for ps in a.public_subnets : {
        id = a.id
        cidr = ps.cidr
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "public_principal_association" {
  for_each = {
    for account_id in local.public_ram : account_id.id => account_id...
  }

  principal          = each.key
  resource_share_arn = aws_ram_resource_share.ci_vpc_share.arn
}
```

I loop over the accounts and it includes the "523134851043" account id which leads into this error.

```
│ Error: error reading RAM Resource Share (arn:aws:ram:eu-central-1:523134851043:resource-share/d958c0c7-555e-411b-ac6b-3302a901408b) Principal Association (523134851043), status not associating or associated: FAILED
│
│   with aws_ram_principal_association.public_principal_association["523134851043"],
│   on ram.tf line 47, in resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "public_principal_association":
│   47: resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "public_principal_association" {
```

I've updated the for expression as mentioned by Matt

```
resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "private_principal_association" {
  for_each = {
    for account_id in local.private_ram : account_id.id => account_id... if !(can(regex("523134851043", account_id)))

  }
```

But terraform still wants to create this resource

```
  # aws_ram_principal_association.private_principal_association["523134851043"] will be created
  + resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "private_principal_association" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + principal          = "523134851043"
      + resource_share_arn = (known after apply)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution made it for me

```
resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "public_principal_association" {
  for_each = {
    for account_id in local.public_ram : account_id.id => account_id... if ! contains(values(account_id), "523134851043")
  }

  principal          = each.key
  resource_share_arn = aws_ram_resource_share.ci_vpc_share.arn
}
```

[How to remove values from a map in Terraform that match a key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463671/how-to-remove-values-from-a-map-in-terraform-that-match-a-key-value)